# How to cancel pending formation of wallet contract in Mist?

Tags: ether, mist, wallets, gas

I have an (empty) account with no Ether in it yet. In **Mist**, I created a wallet contract since I thought I needed it to receive Ether. However, I know now that this is not the case.

The wallet contract creation process however is still pending. It is greyed out and states "Creating..."

I am about to receive some ETH on the account sometime soon.

Now, I read that starting a wallet contract actually requires gas. I am guessing this is also the reason why, thus far, my wallet contract has failed to get created.

**Since however I do not need any wallet contract, how can I cancel it while it is still pending creation**?

Also, do I need to fear that as soon as I transfer some Ether to my account it will be used as gas to finalize the creation process of my Wallet Contract? Or could I somehow prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by changing to the solo network and back to the main network via the developer tools. After that the wallet contract was disappeared.